# LM317 adjustable constant current source - Why is the voltage between Output and Adj pins is not always 1.25V?

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current, lm317

I am trying to create an adjustable constant current circuit using LM317 to drive LEDs of different colors.

More specifically, I want the brightness of the LEDs to be the same, therefore, the current flowing through them will be different for different colors. I searched online and found this [circuit](http://imajeenyus.com/electronics/20160530_adjustable_current_source/index.shtml), which outputs a current between 125-400 mA.

[image]

I want the current to be between 1-3 mA, so I played around with the resistance values of R1, R2 and R3 (potentiometer.) When I tried certain resistance values (R1 = 10k, R2 = 2k and R3 = 50k), I found that the voltage between the output and adjustment pins is not always 1.25 V. Why is this so? Are there limits to which resistance values we have to use in order to maintain a potential difference of 1.25 V across the output and adjustment pins?

(P.S. I am supplying 9V into the LM317.)

Comment: I had a similar question. see if it helps: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495243/understanding-the-application-of-a-switching-regulator-as-a-constant-current-led

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Hi, thank you for sharing but I have found the answers to my problems. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to keep it in regulation, there must be a minimum current draw from the regulator output. In general this is in 5-10 mA range but feel free to read the datasheet of the specific component you have.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the minimum current draw from the regulator output. As such, I went to measure the output voltage and found that the difference between the input and output voltages was lesser than 3 V (it has to be greater than 3 V for the 1.25 V to appear right?). From the datasheet, I also observe that the output voltage is affected by the resistance values. So, thank you, I think I have found the answer from the hint you gave. :)